# how do i write a favicon line of code for my own new website?

Tags: html, dreamweaver, favicon

i am creating my own website, however, i am quite new to coding and was wondering how to write the favicon line of code so that my logo appears at the top on the tab.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks
:)

Answer (score 1):

You can put this in your html:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

However; most browsers find it perfectly fine without this tag, if you upload a file called /favicon.ico :)